# libgdx - How to set model rotation pivot?

Tags: android, libgdx, rotation

By default, the modelInstance is rotated by its centre (0,0,0), I want it to rotate by (0,2,2). I know that in other game engines, there is method like `model.setRotationPivot(float)`, is there any similar method in libgdx?

```
// how to set rotation pivot?   
modelInstance.transform.set(position, rotation, scale);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want to rotate your texture? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @JasonSingh, I want to rotate the 3d model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer:

As I know there is no method to set the pivot.
I use a workaround for this.

```
Vector3 vec3 = new Vector3(0, 2, 2);
vec3.rotate(Vector3.Y, rotation);
modelInstance.transform.setToTranslation(vec3);
this.transform.rotate(Vector3.Y, rotation);
```